# Missing "Signing in to Google" to Get Security Code

Tags: authentication

I am trying to sync Google Drive with MultCloud and I am asked to authenticate myself by using the ""Signing in to Google;" however, this is missing from my phone. I am unable to enter the 2FA from the authentication app in the phone.

The image below illustrates the instructions I am given: [Verify it's you
There is something unusual about your activity. For your security, Google wants to make sure it's really you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJOLV.png)

I am not very lucky getting effective support from Google Product Support forums, what can I do to authenticate myself through the regular authentication app or phone number

For some reason, the more ways to verify link is not listing my authenticator or phone number. This image illustrates the message I am getting

[Choose a way to verify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpHpQ.png)

Also, I am disabled from changing the multi-factor authentication methods from my account because I am asked for this security code from the "Log in to Google" setting which is missing from the phone (I just tried to do that, but same situation).I am not presented with other alternatives like the getting a text or the Authenticator App (I just tried that)

Comment: is your phone number connected with the google account your are using for this? google account / security / your devices....

Comment: Yes Zina, the phone is connected with the Google account

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using a smartphone app, not about using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]. Try [android.se] or [apple.se].

Comment: fwiw, I'm experiencing the same issue logging in to Google via a web app, so it's not just phone specific.